Prevent users from visiting a 'form-sent confirmation page' unless they arrive there through the form
I have a webform which allows users to submit their data.
Note: The data is not stored on the server, but is sent to an email address.
When the user clicks the 'Submit' button, the form-handler redirects the user to a 'Sent Confirmation' page, which reads...  "Thank you for submitting your form."
header('location: /sentconfirmation.php');
The problem with this is, the user can simply type: (example) mywebsite.com/sentconfirmation.php into their broswer, and take a screenshot to claim they have sent their form in, when they actually haven't.
Is there a way to prevent the user from accessing the sent confirmation page directly, and only arrive there through actually sending the form?
Or perhaps a way to mask the url of the sent confirmation page?

This sounds like an XY problem. An image like the one you mention can still be produced without any involvement of your server. If you're worried about people forging receipts, then you should generate some unique and unpredictable token that you can use as a reference and display on the confirmation page, so that you can easily detect forgeries.

@Siguza Yes, I considered printing the user's name and current date/time on the confirmation page.

Again, that won't help though because it's trivial to fake.

Yes, it's possible to achieve this. In this case, most probably, I would use PHP's session feature.
You can store the form submission status in the session and based on that, you can allow users to that page or block otherwise.
Here's how I would do this:
Make sure both of your page can use PHP's session feature, by adding the following line on top of both of your pages:
<?php
session_start();

Before the redirection header add the following line:
<?php
$_SESSION['form_submitted'] = true;
header('location: /sentconfirmation.php');

You can check for this value on the redirection page.
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['form_submitted']) || $_SESSION['form_submitted'] !== true) {
    // Redirect to the form page if the session variable is not set
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit;
}

// Unset the session variable to prevent users from refreshing the page and seeing it again
unset($_SESSION['form_submitted']);

// Display your confirmation message
echo "Thank you for submitting your form.";

Hope this helps.
